# Why are double frees an error the OS or memory allocator handles instead of a simple potential logic error?

Tags: memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

Can’t the memory allocator simply silently silently ignore any frees of an already freed resource?

Of course, double freeing could still be a logical error, as reallocation could mean that the second (or later) free frees a used resource, but why does it have to be an error that the OS/memory allocator handles?

Comment: The behavior is undefined. An implementation could ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessarily an error that is detected.  Some allocators may catch some invalid frees some of the time; other times they will cause some form of corruption that will likely cause problems in subsequent alloc/free operations.   Problems of that sort are often difficult to diagnose; so it is a true favour when it can be pointed out as soon as possible.

The problem isn't the allocator; it is that the program using it is being careless.   Programs shouldn't be careless with memory; and if managing memory is too cumbersome, there are lots of great languages (Go comes to mind) that manage it for you.